# Unary operators and ++ or --

Tags: c

Why in the C specification only the prefix increment and decrement operators
are summarized as Unary operators?

In fact the postﬁx increment and decrement operators are summarized into the section Postfix operators.

I don't see the difference. Both operate on a sole operand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**REWRITTEN**: I guess I mis-read the spec, as pointed out by @Lundin. A better answer seems to be that the names used in this part of the standard don't make a lot of sense.

Of course both postfix and prefix increment/decrement are both just as unary as the other. That's how they're used. The fact that they have different priorities mean that they are put in different groups, and the groups have historical names which are a bit off.

Comment: -1 because I don't believe this answers the question. For each group of operators anywhere in the chapter 6.5, the previous group is specified, to show which group that takes precedence. Since the postfix operators have higher precedence than the unary ones, they are listed in the syntax you have cited, and for that reason alone. They are _not_ part of the same group! All postfix operators have higher precedence than the prefix ("unary") ones.

Comment: @Lundin Ah, I was fooled by the apparent structure. Thanks. I edited to reflect this interpretation, but I can't delete the answer since it's accepted. :/

Comment: To be fair, the whole of 6.5 is one of the most confusing chapters of the whole standard. They should have included a operator precedence table in the standard document, instead of letting the order of the sub chapters determine precedence.

Answer (score 3):

You are referring to the C standard, of which one draft of one version is [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf).

The reason why postfix inc/decrement are in a different section than prefix inc/decrement is that this part of the standard follows the grammar, and that in order to remove ambiguity, these operators are at different levels of the grammar:

```
unary-expression: 
  postfix-expression
  ++ unary-expression
  -- unary-expression
  ...


postfix-expression:
  primary-expression
  ...
  postfix-expression ++
  postfix-expression --
```

This allows an expression such as `++ E ++` (while such an expression would never be valid anyway) to be parsed unambiguously as `++(E++)`).

Answer (score 2):

@Pascal Cuoq answered why they are in different groups: it is because they have different precedence and for no other reason. It has little to do with whether they are actually unary or binary operators.

The reason why the C uses confused names for the operator groups is most likely this classic, yet incorrect table:

**K&R 2nd edition page 48.**
[image]

This table is to blame for a lot of evil in the world. K&R originally listed "everything unary" as one operator group. But of course this is correct: it doesn't make sense for the postfix ++ -- to be grouped with the prefix operators.

As C was standardized, the committee likely realized that this table didn't make any sense, so they made additional groups. Out of the two top groups in the K&R table, they made three. One group for primary expression (plain parenthesis `()` included there), one group for postfix ones and one group still called unary, likely because of historical reasons. A better name for the latter would no doubt have been prefix operators, but the C standard isn't exactly known to be rational.

Comment: *This table is to blame for a lot of evil in the world.* -- Don't you think that overstates the case? Incidentally, K&R2 was based on the ANSI standard, which was nearly complete when the book was first published in 1988, so I don't think your suggested timeline applies.

Comment: @KeithThompson Given that the ANSI standard had pretty much the same operator groups as C still has today, that only makes the case worse. Why didn't they update this misleading table to reflect the operator groups in the standard? I'm guessing that this table is a remain from the 1st edition, though since I haven't read the 1st edition, that's just speculation.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that it is just a question of structure of the standard. The C11 standard has a special section for postfix operators, so they are not classified with the rest of infix and prefix operators. Mathematically, they are of course unary.

Comment: `[] . ->` and several other postfix operators are not mathematically/logically unary, but rather binary. Postfix ++ -- is listed together with those because they have the same operator precedence.

Comment: @Lundin: By "they", I was referring to postfix `++` and postfix `--`. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Postfix operators are left-associative, and Unary operators are right-associative.

Secondly, Postfix operators have higher precedence than Unary operators.