# printf printing 2 times output in C

Tags: c

I have just started learning C through book K&R.
This is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (){
    int c;
    char value = ((c = getchar()) != EOF);
    while (value){
        printf(" %c\n", c);
        printf("%d :: value : %d\n",__LINE__,value);
        value = ((c = getchar()) != EOF);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This results in

```
a
 a
10 :: value : 1


10 :: value : 1
b
 b
10 :: value : 1


10 :: value : 1
```

I don't understand why it is printing `value` 2 times?

Comment: Take out the first `printf`. I don't think you need it.

Comment: value should be declared as bool... and code like `value = ((c = getchar()) != EOF);` is an excellent example of why you shouldn't learn C programming from K&R.

Comment: @Lundin : I thought K&R is most recommended book for learning C.

Comment: That's only because of nostalgia and because there's so many who have learned C through that book over the years, not because the book is any good. For historical reasons, it has the status of the "C bible" and therefore the fanatic, religious believers won't tolerate any criticism against it. And no, I don't have any other book recommendations, been many years since I last read a C programming book.

Comment: @Lundin: I disagree. K&R is highly recommended, and for good reason. The coding style can be a bit terse, but in the case of an input loop `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)` (not quite the same as what's in the question) really is, IMHO, the best way to do it.

Comment: @KeithThompson For what good reason is it highly recommended? I suppose it might be a fun challenge to have the book, the 5 page errata and the current C standard before you on the table. Then try to find out if a certain page is correct, outdated or full of errors. Like a puzzle! Reward yourself with a cookie for each error you find! Though please ignore bad coding style, non-portable code and reliance on poorly-defined behavior: to eat that many cookies is not healthy!

Comment: @Lundin: It's highly recommended because it's a good book. Like any book, it has errors (and there's an [errata list](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/cbook/2ediffs.html) at the Bell Labs web site), but I know of no *major* errors. Are we both talking about the 2nd edition? (The 1st edition is mostly of historical interest.) Coding style is a matter of opinion; K&R does tend to be a little terse for my taste, but not fatally so. I find your criticism short on specifics (which I suppose is unavoidable given the limits of the comment system).

Comment: @KeithThompson There are many major errors in the 2nd edition. One such example is the incomplete and incorrect operator precedence table at 2.12, which has likely caused millions of misunderstandings and bugs over the years. The problems with it are explained more in detail [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116172/unary-operators-and-or/24118257#24118257).

Comment: Ok, I didn't know about that. I'm skeptical that that table has caused "millions of misunderstandings and bugs over the years". I don't know whether the errata list is still being maintained; if it is, you might want to submit it; perhaps you can contact Brian Kernighan. We're not going to settle this in comments.

Comment: The book definitely has attained biblical status. I think it's important to separate the philosophical and historical significance of the book from its modern utility. C has come a long, long way (C89, C99, C11, and the ongoing efforts) since the book was written. There are plenty of things in the book that are definitely unnecessarily esoteric because that used to be the status quo (like conflating the concepts of equality testing and variable assignment). Still a great read, but not for modern best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this simple change in your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int c;
    char value = ((c = getchar()) != EOF);
    while (value)
    {
        printf(" %d\n", c); //print the int value of the character
        printf("%d :: value : %d\n",__LINE__,value);
        value = ((c = getchar()) != EOF);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And now the output becomes:

```
a
 97 <-- ascii code of 'a'
9 :: value : 1
 10 <-- ascii code of newline (line feed)
9 :: value : 1
b
 98 <-- ascii code of 'b'
9 :: value : 1
 10
9 :: value : 1
abcd <-- you could also do this
 97
9 :: value : 1
 98
9 :: value : 1
 99
9 :: value : 1
 100
9 :: value : 1
 10
9 :: value : 1
<...>
```

Showing that every time you read a character a newline (ASCII 10 character) also comes along.

Comment: I did these changes in my program.And you are correct :)
But if `getchar()` is blocking call,then how does my program prints
 2 times without getting blocked at `getchar()`?
I mean does getchar stores 2 values at a time in variable `c`?

Comment: Not sure what your dilemma is. Of course it blocks. But it only blocks after it consumes it's input stream. In your case you give it 2 characters in your input stream: 'a' and a newline. It consumes them in 2 iterations then it blocks waiting ...

Comment: Wow: a -1 accepted answer: They should make a badge for that!

Comment: because I understood it in such a way that I can explain it to my granddaughters & great grand daughters. :)
I don;t get why it is downvoted?

Comment: A clearer and more idiomatic way to write that loop is: `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) { /* ... */ }`. Repeating the call at the top and bottom of the loop is unnecessary and error-prone.

Answer (score 3):

Not twice it's only once. Another one is your input.
For example, you input 'a', the console will display 'a' first, then you program will print one more time when run to the statement:

```
printf(" %c\n", c);
```

Answer (score 2):

This will continue to execute those two printf()s until you encounter EOF on stdin, which will probably signaled by EOT (control D, or control Z on some platforms).

The reason for this is because of the pre-test condition while(value), wherein value is computed as:

```
((c = getchar()) != EOF);
```

This means do a blocking read from stdin for one character, storing it in the stack allocated integer c, and then store the result of the comparison with EOF into the char value. Which means that the char value should really probably be a bool, and not a char, as its value will only ever be zero or one.

Answer (score 2):

`getchar()` is reading two characters - the letter you typed, and the newline character when you pressed "enter".

Answer (score 0):

It is simply because you first see the character you just typed at the terminal and, then, the character that is printed by the program (second one a little bit shifted on the right).

But, if you where speaking about `value`, it appears only once. The left most value is the content of the variable `__LINE__` and the other one is `value` (see *`printf` format strings* to know more about it).